# Is there a way of limiting the scope of mousewheel in a large form

Tags: delphi

The project is in Delphi5

I have a form that will display a variable number of panels, large enough that the form will grow much larger than the screen can display at one time.

I have used the following to allow the mouse wheel to scroll up and down

```
ScrollBy(0, WheelDelta);
```

It works fine but you can scroll past the top or bottom of the form.

Is there a way of limiting the scope of the scroll?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Don

Comment: Calculate and limit your scrolling in code, there's no automatic way of limiting ScrollBy.

Comment: `ScrollBy(0, Min(ClientHeight - (BottomMostPanel.Top + BottomMostPanel.Height), WheelDelta));`

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, shouldn't that be the answer?

Comment: Thank you.  That looked to work at first.

Comment: Hit <ENTER> too soon.  That code does alter the wheel.  However I can scroll downward any distance I want after the last panel.  When I then Scroll back to the top I end up about 500-600 (estimate) from the top of the form.  I can no longer get to the panels above.  Plus the vertical scroll bar works up to the first instance of using the wheel and then disappears.

Comment: All that line does is to limit DeltaY - when scrolling in the positive direction only, it was an example... After a point, it provides a DeltaY of 0. I can hardly imagine you can scroll any distance after the last panel using that code..

Comment: @Johan - Not sure. A better answer would probably to set the [AutoScroll](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TScrollingWinControl.AutoScroll) of the form. I'm not exactly clear about the question.

Comment: @Sertac I understood from OPs comment that he already has AutoScroll set, and that he want to use the mousewheel (anywhere on the form) in addition to the scrollbar.

Comment: @Tom - In that case I'd just read `SPI_GETWHEELSCROLLLINES` and perform that many `(WM_VSCROLL, SB_LINEDOWN|UP, 0)`. No need for any calculation or limit... I guess your answer is even better. But notice that there's no reaction from the poster to your answer.

Comment: @Sertac Yes, API has mostly the solution and you have a great knowledge of that. Indeed, I noticed the "lack of gratitude" although OP has been around since. Maybe he only reacts when advice doesn't work, or maybe its ignorance of how to behave ;) He should at least [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 3):

Since you have the vertical scrollbar visible, it is better to act on that instead of calling `ScrollBy`.

```
procedure TForm1.FormMouseWheel(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
  WheelDelta: Integer; MousePos: TPoint; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  VertScrollBar.Position := VertScrollBar.Position-WheelDelta;
  Handled := True;
end;
```

The scrollbar limits changes to its top position and maximum scroll position

Comment: That worked perfectly!  Thank you.  I saw a comment earlier about not responding to someone's suggestion and I apologize.  I sometimes post a question and then forget where I did it.  This time I got an email that said there were responses.

Comment: @dcboje Here on SO (in fact all StackExchange sites) we up-vote (/ down-vote) questions and answers that we find useful (/ terrible). In addition (or separately) the asker can mark an answer as the correct one by clicking the tick mark below the vote buttons on the left. These actions are described in the "tour" and elsewhere in "help" which you access through the "help" button at the top.